# Listing card not retrieving in stripe

Tags: javascript, api, curl, stripe-payments

When using the [Stripe API for list all cards](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list) I'm not receiving all cards.

It is displaying only the cards which Id starting with `card_xx`.Some cards are starting with `pm_xx` as card id which is added using a mobile app.
I need to display both kind of cards.

Comment: Cards and "Payment Methods" are different things. You'll have to fetch both, or convert cards to PMs as that's the direction Stripe is moving in. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning

Comment: @ceejayoz How can fetch both.can you hint me

Comment: Same way you fetch cards, but with https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list.

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz ans here will approve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ceejayoz

Its done by https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=node to receive all payment methods.